# StringTokenizer.countTokens() returning erroneous value in for loop condition

Tags: java, for-loop, stringtokenizer

We have to calculate numbers of "this" in a given string having multiple "this" substrings. Eg. "Hello this is a recruit and this is a veteran and this is this"
would return 4.

So I am using:

```
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer1 = new StringTokenizer(input2);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count=0;
    int arrIndex = stringTokenizer1.countTokens();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringTokenizer1.countTokens(); i++) 
    {
        arrayList1.add(stringTokenizer1.nextToken());
    }

    for (String string2 : arrayList1) 
    {
        if (string2.equals(string)) 
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    output1 = count;
    System.out.println(output1);
```

return only 2.

However, if `int arrindex` is assigned with the value of stringTokenizer1.countTokens() and used in looping condition, it's giving the correct result of 4. WHY??

Note:Using JavaSE-1.6

Comment: Have you debugged and checked whats being executed and not?

Comment: yes I have debugged using print statements as i am a newbee

Comment: From the [JavaDoc for `StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html); _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code._ Don't use it.

Comment: Can you give us a minimal executeable example of yor code?

Comment: @Jens yes use this link: http://pastie.org/9329551

Comment: @ReXdean never post code on external links.

Comment: @BoristheSpider So should i paste the code as question and then link it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `stringTokenizer1.countTokens()` is evaluated everytime you reenter the loop.

[Per the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#countTokens%28%29)

> Calculates the number of times that this tokenizer's nextToken method can be called  before it generates an exception. The current position is not advanced.

That means `countTokens()` will change everytime you call `nextToken()`

With your example :

1. for i=0, countTokens=4 -> enter the loop -> call to nextToken() -> countTokens=3
2. for i=1, countTokens=3 -> enter the loop -> call to nextToken() -> countTokens=2
3. for i=2, countTokens=2 -> exit the loop

Answer (score 3):

That's because when you're doing stringTokenizer1.nextToken(), you're changing the state of the tokenizer, and you will have one token less left to read.